# How to exclude some numbers of a list in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to use a list in a for loop in python, but I want to exclude some of its data. My list includes numbers from 13 to 50 and I want to exclude 19, 26, 33, 40 and so on. In other words they are `12+7`, `12+7*2`, `12+7*3`, `12+7*4` and so on. This is my for loop:

```
for i in range (13,50):
    if i==19 or i==26 or i==33 or i==40 or i==47:
        continue
    print (i)
```

In real cases I have thousands of points and I cannot work with the `if` line. In advance, I do appreciate a  solution.

Comment: First you should generate the required list like [19,26,33] (by calculating before your for loop)
then you can simple use `if i in newList: continue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be,

```
for i in range(13,50):
    if (i-12)%7 == 0: # Can also use i % 7 == 5
        continue
    print(i)
```

else you can generate a list which contains all those values and work it out like

```
l = [12+7, 12+7*2,....]
for i in range(13,50):
    if i in l:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: `i % 7 == 5` would be a simpler way of putting that condition.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can create your excludedList.

```
Nmax = 5
excludedList = [12 + 7 * i for i in range(1, Nmax)]
```

Now you can check if the value of your iterator is in excludedList or not

```
for i in range (13,50):
    if i in excludedList :
        continue
    print (i)
```

Comment: `excludedList` can be a set, but a modulo based approach would probably be better still.

Comment: Thanks @Jasmijn, he will choose the answer according to what he wants to do